# My program is showing no errors but won't print results to a label in TKinter for Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I wrote this program and was trying to learn TKinter GUI.  I get no errors when I run the program and it looks good with the GUI, I then enter the values in the boxes and hit calculate button and nothing happens, I would like to find out why nothing is put in the result label at the bottom of the GUI.

Thanks for any help.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def calculate(*args):
    try:
        if elevud.get() == 'u':
            elev = float(elevation.get()) / 3
            dist = float(distance.get()) + elev
        else:
            elev = float(elevation.get()) / 3
            dist = float(distance.get()) - elev
        if windfb.get() == 'f':
            w = float(wind.get()) * 1.75
            dist = dist + w
        else:
            w = float(wind.get()) * 0.75
            dist = dist - w
        newDistance.set(dist)

    except ValueError:
        pass


root = Tk()
root.title("TGC Disctance Calculator")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding = "3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = (N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

distance = StringVar()
elevation = StringVar()
wind = StringVar()
windfb = StringVar()
elevud = StringVar()
newDistance = StringVar()

distance_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 7, textvariable = distance)
distance_entry.grid(column = 2, row = 1, sticky = (W, E))
elevation_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 7, textvariable = elevation)
elevation_entry.grid(column = 2, row = 2, sticky = (W, E))
elevud_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 7, textvariable = elevud)
elevud_entry.grid(column = 2, row = 5, sticky = (W, E))
wind_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 7, textvariable = wind)
wind_entry.grid(column = 2, row = 3, sticky = (W, E))
windfb_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 7, textvariable = windfb)
windfb_entry.grid(column = 2, row = 4, sticky = (W, E))

ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "Distance").grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "Elevation").grid(column = 1, row = 2, sticky = W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "Up or Down [u/d]").grid(column = 1, row = 3, sticky = W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "Wind Speed").grid(column = 1, row = 4, sticky = W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "Wind Direction [f/b]").grid(column = 1, row = 5, sticky = W)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text = "Calculate", command = calculate).grid(column = 2, row = 6, sticky = W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "Corrected Distance ").grid(column = 1, row = 7, sticky = W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable = newDistance).grid(column = 2, row = 7, sticky = E)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children():  child.grid_configure(padx = 5, pady = 5)


distance_entry.focus()
root.bind('<Enter>', calculate)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: On a side note, `root.bind('<Enter>', calculate)` won't actually work. `<Enter>` isn't a valid keybind. If you want the enter key use `root.bind('<Return>', calculate)`. Also which label isn't displaying anything? Everything seems to be working fine

Comment: Ok I'll switch that, but in the documentation it said for a Windows machine to use <Enter>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow you got the positioning of your text boxes mixed up. `elevud` should be in row 3, not row 5; and so on.

```
distance_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 7, textvariable = distance)
distance_entry.grid(column = 2, row = 1, sticky = (W, E))
elevation_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 7, textvariable = elevation)
elevation_entry.grid(column = 2, row = 2, sticky = (W, E))
elevud_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 7, textvariable = elevud)
elevud_entry.grid(column = 2, row = 3, sticky = (W, E))
wind_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 7, textvariable = wind)
wind_entry.grid(column = 2, row = 4, sticky = (W, E))
windfb_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 7, textvariable = windfb)
windfb_entry.grid(column = 2, row = 5, sticky = (W, E))
```

As it was originally, entering "u" in the third text box would cause `wind` to be "u" rather than `elevud`, which would cause `float(wind.get())` to crash because "u" can't be converted to a float. Note that it's easier to debug these sorts of things if you don't `pass` when you encounter an exception.

Incidentally, `<Enter>` doesn't trigger whenever the enter key is pressed. It triggers whenever the mouse cursor enters the boundaries of a widget. Were you thinking of `<Return>`?

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a try.

Comment: I don't get what you mean row 3 not row 5?  'elevud' is already in row 3.

Comment: Your code says `elevud_entry.grid(column = 2, row = 5, sticky = (W, E))`, so it's in row 5, not row 3.

Comment: Ahhh ok I see.   That was it, works just fine now thanks for the help.